# Why to use static with propTypes

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to React and was learning propTypes and the ways to implement them in React. One of the ways of propType implementation is via class fields, that is,

```
class Foo extends React.Component {
    static PropTypes = {};
}
```

The question is why need to use static for propTypes and is it ok to omit static? I really hope for your beginner-friendly explanation since I have looked through the answer here [react: why static propTypes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40514574/react-why-static-proptypes) but did not properly understand WHY?

Comment: What is not clear about https://stackoverflow.com/a/40514594/4106994 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Static props are those that belong to the class, not to an instance. This means that one class is shared throughout the  entire application. This is known as the [singleton pattern](https://www.dofactory.com/javascript/singleton-design-pattern). The reason you would do this is because propTypes do not belong to a single instance, as mentioned in the question you linked. propTypes are used for type checking the props passed in, so there is no need for them to be tied to specific instances:

https://blog.logrocket.com/validating-react-component-props-with-prop-types-ef14b29963fc/

Comment: thank you for your answer, can I imagine static like this, if we use static method or variable in a class, then it means static will belong to all objects of that class that will be created. I mean static means general belonging to all objects just one static method or variable for all objects created Is that right? Secondly, it might seem a bit weird to you but what is utility functions in your own simple words the reason I am asking is that I read that static is used to create utility functions. Thank you in advance :)

Comment: I wouldn't say that static variables belong to all objects because you would not access them the same way you would access instance variables (i.e., using `this`). I would say they belong to the type, or class. Regarding utility functions, they are helper functions that can be used in many different places. Usually they have a very concise and specific purpose, like replacing all invalid characters from a string for example. Because they are being utilized by external objects and have no state of their own they're good candidates for static functions.

Answer (score 1):

It is not OK to omit `static`, because the PropTypes library is expecting a class property when it looks for your prop definitions. If you omit `static`, you are defining an instance property, which is not how the library operates. Omitting the keyword will result in an instance property and your props will not be validated as expected.

If the `static` keyword is confusing, just think of it as doing the same exact thing as the following:

```
class Foo extends React.Component {
  static propTypes = {}
}

// equivalent to

class Foo extends React.Component {}

Foo.propTypes = {}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, can I imagine static like this, if we use static method or variable in a class, then it means static will belong to all objects of that class that will be created. I mean static means general belonging to all objects just one static method or variable for all objects created Is that right? Secondly, it might seem a bit weird to you but what is utility functions in your own simple words the reason I am asking is that I read that static is used to create utility functions. Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Actually the opposite ... static properties belong to the class itself and will not be inherited by any instances of that class. Regarding utility functions, static properties are a great place to store functions that are related to a class but not necessarily with any individual instance of a class. For example, you might have a static method `create` that returns a new instance of the class it was called on.